# Diodes when voltage is applied

Tags: diodes, semiconductors, pn-junction

Does the hole injection take place from p semiconductor to n semiconductor in a pn junction diode?  Or it takes place only in the case of a transistor?

Comment: Yes. Hole injection from p to n happens in forward biased pn-junction. Which applies to diode and transistor.

Comment: Holes injection create a more positive charge,  which gives rise to amplification.. Does this happen in case of diode??

Comment: It's part of the reason (or all -- I can't remember the details) why a diode has a non-zero reverse recovery time.  The depletion zone gets filled with carriers, and it takes time to clear them out.

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding the source of amplification. Ordinary diodes do not amplify signals on their own, no.